# Typo3 / blank Templates

Tags: templates, bootstrap-4, typo3

I'm a greenhorn with typo3 templating. Actually I'm using "bootstrap_package" (standard layout). I would like to create a sub-page without logo, menu and footnote. I just want to have the content elements on a blank page. How do I do this? Can anyone help me?

Best regards

cgroughy

Answer (score 0):

You should give some more information why you need such a special rendering to get some more detailed help.
The usual reasons for such a page are design flaws as there are more suitable solutions inside TYPO3.

In general: You need to create a new page rendering, where you switch off the generation of the HTML header.

---

add on:

make a page where you collect all the pages which should be available in this special rendering. This page should be a subpage from your root-page. regarding relaurl: `[x] exclude from path`

in this page create a typoscript template record.

as these pages need only one rendering I propose to modify the default page object instead of creating a new page object (with a new `typeNum`).

in the setup field of this template record remove all headers with:

```
config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1
```

You might need to disable further CSS and JS, especially if they are loaded at the end of the page.

if you need another html-markup than the default you can modify the configuration here: wraps, (fluid-)templates, ...

Then add your special pages with content.

Comment: I would like an integration of typo3 content elements (like calendar, results) in siberiancms.

Comment: do you want a normal website, where the same content should be available in siberiancms? or just some special single pages?

Comment: No, not the whole website, just some single pages!

Comment: answer adapted.